# Trying to get all file IDs in folders in Google Drive

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to extract all the file IDs from Drive with Python, building my code in Wing IDE, but I'm having trouble extracting the file IDs out from files within folders.

I can't find any solutions on the web, hence posting this in hopes to get some help.

I'm an amateur in programming, so I don't really know where to even begin.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Is this library useful for your situation? https://github.com/tanaikech/getfilelistpy

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use the Q parameter in the [files.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list?q=mimeType%20!%253D%20%2522application%252Fvnd.google-apps.folder%2522&fields=files%252Fid&_h=4&) method. by adding the following it will make a request for all the files that are not directories

```
q=mimeType+!%3D+%22application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%22
```

Then you can add the fields parameter to only return the id of the file

```
fields=files%2Fid
```

The full request request will look like this

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=mimeType+!%3D+%22application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%22&fields=files%2Fid&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

As for the python part i recomend you follow this sample [Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) it will get you started in using the API with python once you understand how that works you can move on to adding the q and fields parameters to it.

```
# Call the Drive v3 API
results = service.files().list(
    pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
items = results.get('files', [])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way that make more sense.
after installing Python and Gam you can run a script that uses the file id from google drive in a csv file to export all the documents form the list. Once python and gam is installed you will need to install some modules for the script to work. When you run the script the error codes can be googled to see what needs to be installed in Python. Also you will need to create an api credential service account and replace that account name with in the script in both places.
Run cmd as administrator with the following command with a script name of script.py. 
"C:\Users\dcahoon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe C:\GAM\SCRIPT.PY
**script start

```
import os
import subprocess

from csv import writer
from csv import reader

# path to googleidlist.csv
csvfile = 'c:\\GAM\\googleidlist.csv'
destination = 'c:\\GAM\\OUTPUT\\'      #Destination for downloaded documents


# Open the input_file in read mode and output_file in write mode
with open(csvfile, 'r') as read_obj, \
        open('output_1.txt', 'w', newline='') as write_obj:
    # Create a csv.reader object from the input file object
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    # Create a csv.writer object from the output file object
    csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
    # Read each row of the input csv file as list
    for row in csv_reader:
         file_id = row[0]
        outcome = subprocess.Popen(['gam', 'user', 'googleserviceaccountname', 'get', 'drivefile', 'id', file_id, 'targetfolder',destination], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        # os.system("gam user david.bruinsma@colonialmed.com show fileinfo "+ file_id + "name")
        filename = subprocess.Popen(['gam', 'user', 'googleserviceaccountname', 'show', 'fileinfo', file_id, 'name' ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = outcome.stdout.readline()
        file_name = filename.stdout.readline()
        print(output)
        # Append the default text in the row / list
        # row.append(filename)
        row.append(output)
        row.append(file_name)
        row.append(file_id)

        # Add the updated row / list to the output file
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

**script end